# Get previous element html() after click in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Supposing I have the following table:

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>John, René<br /><small>2 street of Blue Ocean<br />Canada</small></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="btn">Select</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Travis, Ford<br /><small>12 street of October 5th<br />Canada</small></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="btn">Select</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="box"></div>
```

How after a click on the `Select` button I can get the HTML in the previous `<td>` in the `div#box` ?

Actually I have:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var html = $(this).prev().html();
    $('#box').html(html);
    alert(html);
});
```

jsFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/n1apyqkv/

Thanks.

Comment: This `var html = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').html();` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var html = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').html();
```

the `closest('td')` will go upwards in the dom until a `td` is found, and from the `td` you can now go to `prev` (*which only works for elements under the same parent - aka siblings*)